# Methods for post_order and in_order?

Tags: python

My professor provided me with some of this code to use for our assignment and I've been trying to understand it for the last couple of hours. I saw that some methods such as post order and inorder were missing and I didn't see any of those methods in the lectures. Can someone possibly add the methods for post order and inorder? Not sure what they are. Also, what is the argument for the mytree.put() down below? It keeps saying "TypeError: put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'curr_node'" whenever I try to run the code.

```
class BSTNode:




def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
    


    self.data = data
    self.left_child = left
    self.right_child = right
    self.parent = parent
    self.balance_factor = 0

def __iter__(self):
    
    if self:
        if self.left_child:
            for elem in self.left_child:
                yield elem
        yield self.key
        if self.right_child:
            for elem in self.right_child:
                yield elem


class BinarySearchTree:




def __init__(self):
    
    self.root = None
    self.size = 0

def length(self):
   
    return self.size

def __len__(self):
   
    return self.size

def __iter__(self):
   
    return self.root.__iter__()

def __setitem__(self, data):
   
    self.put(data)

def __getitem__(self, data):
   
    return self.get(data)

def __delitem__(self, data):
    
    self.delete(data)

def __contains__(self, data):
    
    if self._get(data, self.root):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def put(self, data):
    
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = BSTNode(data)
        self.size += 1
    else:
        self._put(data, self.root)

def _put(self, data, curr_node):
   
    if data == curr_node.data:
        return
    if data < curr_node.data:
        if curr_node.left_child is None:
            curr_node.left_child = BSTNode(data, parent=curr_node)
            self.size += 1
        else:
            self._put(data, curr_node.left_child)
    else:
        if curr_node.right_child is None:
            curr_node.right_child = BSTNode(data, parent=curr_node)
            self.size += 1
        else:
            self._put(data, curr_node.right_child)

def get(self, data):
    
    if self.root is None:
        return None
    else:
        node = self._get(data, self.root)
        if node is not None:
            return node.data
        else:
            return None

def _get(self, data, curr_node):
    
    if curr_node is None:
        return None
    else:
        if data == curr_node.data:
            return curr_node
        if data < curr_node.data:
            return self._get(data, curr_node.left_child)
        else:
            return self._get(data, curr_node.right_child)

def delete(self, data):
    
    if self.size == 1 and self.root.data == data:
        self.root = None
        self.size -= 1
    elif self.size > 1:
        node_to_remove = self._get(data, self.root)
        if node_to_remove is not None:
            self.remove(node_to_remove)
            self.size -= 1
        else:
            raise KeyError("Error, data not present in the tree")
    else:
        raise KeyError("Error, data not present in the tree")

def remove(self, curr_node):
    
    parent_node = curr_node.parent
    if (curr_node.left_child is None and curr_node.right_child is None):
        if parent_node.left_child is curr_node:
            parent_node.left_child = None
        else:
            parent_node.right_child = None
    elif (curr_node.left_child is not None and curr_node.right_child is None):
        if parent_node is not None:
            if parent_node.left_child is curr_node:
                parent_node.left_child = curr_node.left_child
            else:
                parent_node.right_child = curr_node.left_child
            curr_node.left_child.parent = parent_node
        else:
            self.root = curr_node.left_child
            curr_node.left_child.parent = None
    elif (curr_node.left_child is None and curr_node.right_child is not None):
        if parent_node is not None:
            if parent_node.left_child is curr_node:
                parent_node.left_child = curr_node.right_child
            else:
                parent_node.right_child = curr_node.right_child
            curr_node.right_child.parent = parent_node
        else:
            self.root = curr_node.right_child
            curr_node.right_child.parent = None
    else:
        succ_node = self.find_min(curr_node.right_child)
        self.remove(succ_node)

        succ_node.parent = parent_node
        if parent_node is not None:
            if parent_node.left_child is curr_node:
                parent_node.left_child = succ_node
            else:
                parent_node.right_child = succ_node
        else:
            self.root = succ_node

        succ_node.left_child = curr_node.left_child
        if curr_node.left_child is not None:
            curr_node.left_child.parent = succ_node

        succ_node.right_child = curr_node.right_child
        if curr_node.right_child is not None:
            curr_node.right_child.parent = succ_node

def find_min(self, curr_node):
    
    if curr_node.left_child is None:
        return curr_node
    else:
        return self.find_min(curr_node.left_child)

def pre_order_traversal(self):
    
    if self.root is None:
        print("Empty Tree")
    else:
        self.pre_order_traversal_helper(self.root)
        print()

def pre_order_traversal_helper(self, node):
    
    if node is None:
        return
    print(node.data, end=" ")
    self.pre_order_traversal_helper(node.left_child)
    self.pre_order_traversal_helper(node.right_child)

def level_order_traversal(self):
    
    if self.root is None:
        print("Empty tree")
    else:
        node_list = [self.root]
        self.level_order_helper(node_list)
        print()

def level_order_helper(self, node_list):
    
    if len(node_list) > 0:
        node = node_list.pop(0)
        print(node.data, end=" ")
        if node.left_child is not None:
            node_list.append(node.left_child)
        if node.right_child is not None:
            node_list.append(node.right_child)

        self.level_order_helper(node_list)


class AVLTree(BinarySearchTree):
def __init__(self):
    
    super().__init__()

def put(self, data):
    
    if self.root is None:
        self.root = BSTNode(data)
        self.size += 1
    else:
        self._put(data, self.root)

def put(self, data, curr_node):
    
    if data == curr_node.data:
        return
    if data < curr_node.data:
        if curr_node.left_child is None:
            curr_node.left_child = BSTNode(data, parent=curr_node)
            self.size += 1
            curr_node.balance_factor += 1
            self.update_balance_insert(curr_node)
        else:
            self._put(data, curr_node.left_child)
    else:
        if curr_node.right_child is None:
            curr_node.right_child = BSTNode(data, parent=curr_node)
            self.size += 1
            curr_node.balance_factor -= 1
            self.update_balance_insert(curr_node)
        else:
            self._put(data, curr_node.right_child)

def update_balance_insert(self, node):
    
    if node.balance_factor == 0:
        return
    elif node.balance_factor == +1:
        if node.parent and node.parent.left_child is node:
            node.parent.balance_factor += 1
            self.update_balance_insert(node.parent)
        elif node.parent and node.parent.right_child is node:
            node.parent.balance_factor -= 1
            self.update_balance_insert(node.parent)
    elif node.balance_factor == -1:
        if node.parent and node.parent.left_child is node:
            node.parent.balance_factor += 1
            self.update_balance_insert(node.parent)
        elif node.parent and node.parent.right_child is node:
            node.parent.balance_factor -= 1
            self.update_balance_insert(node.parent)
    elif node.balance_factor == -2:
        if node.right_child.balance_factor == -1:
            self.rotate_left(node)
        else:
            self.rotate_right(node.right_child)
            self.rotate_left(node)
    elif node.balance_factor == +2:
        if node.left_child.balance_factor == +1:
            self.rotate_right(node)
        else:
            self.rotate_left(node.left_child)
            self.rotate_right(node)
    else:
        raise Exception("Unhandled case - BF outside the range")

def update_balance_delete(self, node):
   
    if node.balance_factor == +1 or node.balance_factor == -1:
        return
    elif node.balance_factor == 0:
        if node.parent and node.parent.left_child is node:
            node.parent.balance_factor += -1
            self.update_balance_delete(node.parent)
        elif node.parent and node.parent.right_child is node:
            node.parent.balance_factor -= -1
            self.update_balance_delete(node.parent)
    elif node.balance_factor == -2:
        if node.right_child.balance_factor == -1:
            self.rotate_left(node)
        else:
            self.rotate_right(node.right_child)
            self.rotate_left(node)
    elif node.balance_factor == +2:
        if node.left_child.balance_factor == +1:
            self.rotate_right(node)
        else:
            self.rotate_left(node.left_child)
            self.rotate_right(node)
    else:
        raise Exception("Unhandled case - BF outside the range")

def rotate_left(self, rot_root):
    
    new_root = rot_root.right_child
    rot_root.right_child = new_root.left_child
    if new_root.left_child != None:
        new_root.left_child.parent = rot_root
    new_root.parent = rot_root.parent
    if rot_root.parent is None:
        self.root = new_root
    else:
        if rot_root.parent.left_child is rot_root:
            rot_root.parent.left_child = new_root
        else:
            rot_root.parent.right_child = new_root
    new_root.left_child = rot_root
    rot_root.parent = new_root
    rot_root.balance_factor = rot_root.balance_factor + 1 - min(new_root.balance_factor, 0)
    new_root.balance_factor = new_root.balance_factor + 1 + max(rot_root.balance_factor, 0)

def rotate_right(self, rot_root):
    
    new_root = rot_root.left_child
    rot_root.left_child = new_root.right_child
    if new_root.right_child != None:
        new_root.right_child.parent = rot_root
    new_root.parent = rot_root.parent
    if rot_root.parent is None:
        self.root = new_root
    else:
        if rot_root.parent.right_child is rot_root:
            rot_root.parent.right_child = new_root
        else:
            rot_root.parent.left_child = new_root
    new_root.right_child = rot_root
    rot_root.parent = new_root
    rot_root.balance_factor = rot_root.balance_factor - 1 - max(new_root.balance_factor, 0)
    new_root.balance_factor = new_root.balance_factor - 1 + min(rot_root.balance_factor, 0)

def delete(self, data):
    
    if self.size == 1 and self.root.data == data:
        self.root = None
        self.size -= 1
    elif self.size > 1:
        node_to_remove = self._get(data, self.root)
        if node_to_remove is not None:
            self.remove(node_to_remove)
            self.size -= 1
        else:
            raise KeyError("Error, data not present in the tree")
    else:
        raise KeyError("Error, data not present in the tree")

def remove(self, curr_node):
    
    parent_node = curr_node.parent
    if (curr_node.left_child is None and curr_node.right_child is None):
        if parent_node.left_child is curr_node:
            parent_node.left_child = None
            parent_node.balance_factor += -1
            self.update_balance_delete(parent_node)
        else:
            parent_node.right_child = None
            parent_node.balance_factor += 1
            self.update_balance_delete(parent_node)
    elif (curr_node.left_child is not None and curr_node.right_child is None):
        if parent_node is not None:
            if parent_node.left_child is curr_node:
                parent_node.left_child = curr_node.left_child
                curr_node.left_child.parent = parent_node
                parent_node.balance_factor += -1
                self.update_balance_delete(parent_node)
            else:
                parent_node.right_child = curr_node.left_child
                curr_node.left_child.parent = parent_node
                parent_node.balance_factor -= -1
                self.update_balance_delete(parent_node)
        else:
            self.root = curr_node.left_child
            curr_node.left_child.parent = None
    elif (curr_node.left_child is None and curr_node.right_child is not None):
        if parent_node is not None:
            if parent_node.left_child is curr_node:
                parent_node.left_child = curr_node.right_child
                curr_node.right_child.parent = parent_node
                parent_node.balance_factor += -1
                self.update_balance_delete(parent_node)
            else:
                parent_node.right_child = curr_node.right_child
                curr_node.right_child.parent = parent_node
                parent_node.balance_factor -= -1
                self.update_balance_delete(parent_node)
        else:
            self.root = curr_node.right_child
            curr_node.right_child.parent = None
    else:
        succ_node = self.find_min(curr_node.right_child)
        self.remove(succ_node)

        curr_node.data = succ_node.data

def pre_order_traversal(self):
    
    if self.root is None:
        print("Empty Tree")
    else:
        self.pre_order_traversal_helper(self.root)
        print()

def pre_order_traversal_helper(self, node):
   
    if node is None:
        return
    print(str(node.data) + "(%d)" % (node.balance_factor))
    self.pre_order_traversal_helper(node.left_child)
    self.pre_order_traversal_helper(node.right_child)

def level_order_traversal(self):
   
    if self.root is None:
        print("Empty tree")
    else:
        node_list = [self.root]
        self.level_order_helper(node_list)
        print()

def level_order_helper(self, node_list):
   
    if len(node_list) > 0:
        node = node_list.pop(0)
        print(str(node.data) + "(%d)" % (node.balance_factor))
        if node.left_child is not None:
            node_list.append(node.left_child)
        if node.right_child is not None:
            node_list.append(node.right_child)

        self.level_order_helper(node_list)


mytree = AVLTree()

mytree.put(131)
mytree.put(121)
mytree.put(122)
mytree.put(132)
mytree.put(115)
mytree.put(415)
mytree.put(321)
mytree.put(315)
mytree.put(111)


print("pre-order traversal:")
mytree.pre_order_traversal()

print("post-order traversal:")
mytree.post_order_traversal()

print("in-order traversal:")
mytree.in_order_traversal()

print("level-order traversal:")
mytree.level_order_traversal()

print("search result for 122:", end=" ")
print(mytree.get(122))

print("deleting 122")
mytree.delete(122)

print("pre-order traversal after delete:")
mytree.pre_order_traversal()

print("post-order traversal after delete:")
mytree.post_order_traversal()

print("in-order traversal after delete:")
mytree.in_order_traversal()

print("level-order traversal after delete:")
mytree.level_order_traversal()
```

Answer (score 0):

In-order traversal looks like this:

- traverse left node
- print current node
- traverse right node

And post-order traversal looks like this:

- traverse left node
- traverse right node
- print current node

I would enourage you to look at what the code is doing in `pre_order_traversal_helper()` and `pre_order_traversal()` and then rework them for in-order and post-order implementations

Either way, here is an in-order implementation:

```
def in_order_traversal(self):
    
    if self.root is None:
        print("Empty Tree")
    else:
        self.in_order_traversal_helper(self.root)
        print()

def in_order_traversal_helper(self, node):
    if node is None:
        return
    self.in_order_traversal_helper(node.left_child)
    print(node.data, end=" ")
    self.in_order_traversal_helper(node.right_child)
```

Also, there are two definitions of the `put()` method in the `AVLTree` class. It looks like the second `put()` method should be called `_put()`